# ICU parsing date with timezone

Tags: java, timezone, datetime-format, icu

I'm parsing using ICU:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm z");
Date date = formatter.parse("10:33 PST");
```

This throws

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "10:33 PST"
```

However, "10:33 GMT" parses well.

ICU.TimeZone knows PST. I run

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST").getDisplayName());
```

And get

```
Pacific Time
```

When I use java.text, it works fine.

Please help